# Class 'Enum' has no 'POWER' member pylint(no-member)

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, constants, enumeration

i am trying to use this function for automatic enumeration of multiple constant, and give me a error in the last line:

> Class 'Enum' has no 'POWER' member pylint(no-member)

The code is:

```
from enum import Enum 

def enum(*sequential, **named):
    enums = dict(zip(sequential, range(len(sequential))), **named)
    return type('Enum', (), enums)

meas = enum("HARMONIC","POWER","VRMS")

print (meas.POWER) #i expected: >1 (type int)
```

I dont undestand this problem. I want a solution or other form for do this. Thanks.

Comment: why aren't you using `Enum`? If `.meas.POWER` is supposed to be an `int` then it really isn't an enum.

Comment: As an aside, please always use the generic [python] tag for *all* python related questions

Answer (score 2):

This code *does not produce an error*, your linter is complaining and you cannot expect your linter to understand a dynamically created class. Just ignore your linter.

So, as a convenience, the `Enum` class already provides what you are trying to recreate, with an API similar to `collections.namedtuple`:

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> Meas = Enum("Meas", "HARMONIC POWER VRMS")
>>> Meas.POWER
<Meas.POWER: 2>
```

I suppose it's unusual that `Enum` is both a base-class and a class-factory.

Note, your own solution would have given you a number greater than `1` if you simply incremented the range you were using:

```
range(1, len(sequential) + 1))
```

Comment: The OP's custom `enum()` combines both `['a', 'list', 'of', 'names']` and `**names` capabilities, while `Enum` would only work with one of the other.